# How to script MacVIM to split windows the way I want

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm just starting to try MacVIM as a primary text editor after years of using vi only when I was sshing into a remote server. After installing the [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) set of extensions, I launch MacVIM from the Terminal with `macvim .` to get a listing of the current directory.

When launching MacVIM in this manner, by default I get two windows, a narrow [NERDtree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) window and a buffer window taking up the rest of the space available and the focus being in the NERDtree window. I want to split the non-NERDtree window into either two equal parts or, failing that, create a new window at least 83 columns wide. From the default setup, I would enter `<CTRL-W>l:vsplit`, and that would do the job.

Of course, I don't want to do that every time, so how do I script it in my `.gvimrc` (or actually, with Janus, `.gvimrc.local`) file? I've tried a number of ways to do this all with no success. Attempts have included `80vsplit`, and

```
<C-W>
l
vsplit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this in my .vimrc to move the cursor to the content panel when vim starts, you may want to put this in your list of commands to get to the right panel before splitting:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree     "run nerdtree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p     "cursor to right
```

Comment: Very helpful. I got it done satisfactorily, but not perfect. I ended up using the second line you gave (Janus is already starting NERDTree) but with `l` instead of `p`, and then added the line `120vsplit`, which give me a middle window of 83 characters. It's still not splitting the second window down the middle, but this is better than what I had.